# how to prevent mirroring of ios app in iphone via quicktime player in Phonegap or Cordova

Tags: ios, swift, cordova, cordova-plugins, drm

I am making an app in  which video is streamed online via MarlinDRM . Is there a plugin or swift or objective c code to prevent screen mirroring / getting an event / blacking out the video via quicktime player and camtasia.

Netflix is avoiding screen mirroring in quicktime player and camtasia.

I have found a plugin [cordova plugin presentation](https://github.com/fraunhoferfokus/cordova-plugin-presentation) which replaces external screen with other web pages when iPhone is connected to mac via airplay.

I am searching for similar plugin which works for quicktime player (wired connection).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an operating system feature so you cannot disable it programmatically within your app.

**Update:**

Netflix streams are not mirrored because they are encrypted live streams. Those media will not be mirrored in general.

Comment: then , how netflix is able to avoid the mirroring in quicktime ?

Comment: Netflix streams are not mirrored because they are encrypted live streams. Those media will not be mirrored in general.

Comment: hey @M_G is there is a way to detect or get an event if ios devices is connected to mac , programmatically?

Comment: Not sure but I would try out the ExternalAccessory framework: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/ExternalAccessory/Reference/ExternalAccessoryFrameworkReference/